# Can't show already added fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Launch app - Fragment A loads
2. Click button on A - Fragment B loads
3. Click button on B - Fragment A loads

This is a method in MainActivity:

```
private fun addBrowseBooksFragment() {

        var browseBooksFragment = BrowseBooksFragment()
        val fragmentManager = fragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        if ((fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("BrowseBooksFragment")) != null){
            browseBooksFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("BrowseBooksFragment") as BrowseBooksFragment

            println("working fine up to here")

            if (browseBooksFragment.isAdded) {
                println("Showing Added Fragment")
                browseBooksFragment.setCallBackInterface(this)
                fragmentTransaction.show(browseBooksFragment)
            }

        } else {
            browseBooksFragment.setCallBackInterface(this)
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, browseBooksFragment, "BrowseBooksFragment")
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
```

The `else` works fine because Fragment A loads without a problem. Fragment B also loads without a problem. But when I click the button to go back to Fragment A, `browseBooksFragment.isAdded` returns false but `browseBooksFragment` is not null. It returns the fragment by tag.

I'm trying to avoid recreating the whole fragment by not using `replace` and instead use `show`.

I should add that if I comment out the `isAdded` condition and change `show` to `replace`, I get a **Fragment already added** exception.

```
//            if (browseBooksFragment.isAdded) {
                println("Showing Added Fragment")
                browseBooksFragment.setCallBackInterface(this)
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, browseBooksFragment, "BrowseBooksFragment")
//                fragmentTransaction.show(browseBooksFragment)
//            }
```

How do I show the already added Fragment A properly?

Comment: Why don't you simply add `addToBackStack` while transacting the fragment? It simply **Add this transaction to the back stack** 

 `fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, list)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();`

Comment: That's because should the user backpress on either Fragment A or B, the app should instantly close.

Comment: I guess, you can avoid instant close by  calling 
`@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
  if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
  else
   super.onBackPressed();
}`

You can add like  `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.home_container, frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `replace()`, you should use `add()`. This way you are not replacing an existing fragment, but instead pushing a fragment B on top of fragment A.

For ex.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction()
   .add("id of your fragment container", fragment, fragment.class.getSimpleName())
   .addToBackStack(fragment.class.getSimpleName())
   .commit();
```

This way if you want to load previous fragment you just have to do

```
fm.popBackStack();
```

And this will pop the fragment B from the BackStack, showing the previously created fragment A.

Comment: Yup, just realized I should be using `add` instead. Thanks!